# Recycler view is not displaying cards/text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have synced the gradle,checked dependencies,removed warning or any errors,rewritten multiple times and even tried different methods/tutorials i could find.Hope someone here could help me.

This is my code:

1. Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

1.MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 1", "Line 2"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 3", "Line 4"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 5", "Line 6"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 7", "Line 8"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 9", "Line 10"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 11", "Line 12"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 13", "Line 14"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 15", "Line 16"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 17", "Line 18"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 19", "Line 20"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 21", "Line 22"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 23", "Line 24"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 25", "Line 26"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 27", "Line 28"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Line 29", "Line 30"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

2.ExampleAdapter.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

3.ExampleItem

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class ExampleItem {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;

    public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return mText2;
    }
}
```

4.example_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

5.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Isnt this code from coding in flow ?

Comment: @CreamyOreo Yup, it is but this is probably the 3rd one i have tried but it just dsn't seem to work,my recycler list is still empty and the data is not displayed on it.Do you spot something I probably am doing wrong?Also thanks for the edit.

Comment: can you check if example list did get parse into the adapter ? To check you can do a Log.v check in the `ovveride itemCount`

Comment: so what was the issue ?